# How to lookup the value of a dictionary inside a dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this `transitionMap: Dictionary<Dictionary<int, char>, int> transitionMap;`

And I also have this `dictionary: Dictionary<int, char> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, char> {{0, 'a'}};`.

How do I get the value inside `transitionMap` that corresponds to `dictionary1`.

This is what I've tried:

```
        Dictionary<int, char> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, char> {{stateNum, symbol}};

        if (this.transitionMap.ContainsKey(dictionary))
        {
            int nextState = this.transitionMap[dictionary];
            Console.WriteLine("nextstate {0}", nextState);
        }
```

Comment: It seems you have *wrong design*: inner `Dictionary<int, char>` should not be a `Key`, but `Value`: `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, char>> transitionMap`

Comment: Wait, so you can't have a dictionary key? @DmitryBychenko

Comment: Techniclly you can (I mean it will be compiled), but note, that two dictionaries are *equal* if and only if they share the same *reference*, in your case it means that  `transitionMap.ContainsKey(dictionary)` will be always `false`

Comment: It makes no sense to have such dictionary. Please tell us why you need this.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ah ok, I get it now, guess I have to change some things up, thanks dude!

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm trying to write a DFA transition function that takes a `state number` and a `symbol` and returns the next state, I figured a map would be easiest to implement such functionality.

Comment: You want check two dictionaries have the same KeyValuePair? That with basic `foreach`?

Comment: @Orwel Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare two dictionaries for equality then having a "super dictionary" will not help you in any way. You will have to manually compare all elements in two dictionaries.

First, compare the number of elements. Then run a loop through one dictionary, and with the key find the value in second dictionary, and if exists compare two values.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Linq :

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var transitionMap = new Dictionary<Dictionary<int, char>, int>();
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, char> { { stateNum, symbol } };

        ...

        var found = transitionMap.Keys.FirstOrDefault(d => Equal(d, dictionary));
        if(found == null)
        {
            int nextState = transitionMap[found];
            Console.WriteLine("nextstate {0}", nextState);
        }
    }

    static bool Equal(Dictionary<int, char> a, Dictionary<int, char> b)
    {
        return a.Count == b.Count && a.All(akv => b.TryGetValue(akv.Key, out char bval) && akv.Value == bval);
    }
}
```